# Understanding the metrics approach for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, metrics

I was going through the [metric/monitoring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) page for spark.

**What I understand**
Spark writes events to event logs to as configured in `spark.eventLog.enabled true` and `spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://path`.
These are accessible in 3 ways

1. Spark History Server
2. REST API
3. SparkListener

**What I dont understand**

1. Can you get all event logs as written in `spark.eventLog.dir` in SparkListener?
2. Do SparkMetrics just calculate metrics based on eventLogs generated or these a disparate set of metrics not visible in spark event logs?

Answer (score 1):

Base- and derived metrics exist 1) during a Job and 2) may be persisted to HDFS for subsequent consumption, use by e.g. History Server.

- The *Spark Listener* runs during the life of the Spark App. It is a class that *listens* to execution events from Spark’s `DAGScheduler` – the main part of the execution engine in Spark. It does not consume from the spark.eventLog.dir; this may have not even been set by the `spark-submit`, etc.
- 2nd question hard to follow. There are always base metrics and derived in any system. As stated they may not be coming from event logs. Given that metrics can be shown as a *median*, then they are also derived aka *disparate* I suspect.